# How to load data to user controls at start up?

Tags: catel

I'm getting started learning MVVM and Catel and have i have problem how to load two user controls with data from a database.

In short, my mainwindow.xaml contains this two rows, (MainViewModel is "empty")

```
<catel:StackGrid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="5">
    <views:View1 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" />
    <views:View2 Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto"/>
</catel:StackGrid>
```

My View1ViewModel loads fine, gets data from database and it displays in View1, however my View2ViewModel does not load.

Should i load my secondview from the firstview or should my rows above do the thing and the error is related to binding in my View2?

Any hints would be nice to get to a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between VM1 and VM2. I see you are using a stackgrid without actually defining any rows / columns. Make sure to define those as well so the view gets actually loaded.

There is no need for you to do anything differently for view 2.